# In Javascript, can a closure share scope with a function return value?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm trying to understand this unexplained code from *Eloquent Javascript* :

```
function trackKeys(keys) {
  let down = Object.create(null);
  function track(event) {
    if (keys.includes(event.key)) {
      down[event.key] = event.type == "keydown";
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("keydown", track);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", track);
  return down;
}

var arrowKeys =
  trackKeys(["ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp"]);
```

I think I understand how the inner function `track` will maintain a reference to `down` and `keys` because it is a closure, but I'm lost at `return down;`

Will that return value be a reference to the exact same `down` the callbacks are accessing? I don't understand; I thought local variables could only be accessed by inner functions?

Follow-up: what if down were a primitive data type and not an object, would this still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function initializes the variable `down` as an object.

So within the function, `down` is a variable that points to a certain object.

When the function returns `down`, it returns a reference to the object, meaning that the object becomes accessible through the return of the function.

If `down` were primitive, then this would not work since the function would only return a primitive value rather than a reference to an object.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Saying "a variable is returned" is ambiguous due to the inherent imprecision of human language. It does not mean that the variable-pairing of identifier and value is returned. It means the *value* of the variable is returned. In this case the value of the reference to the object (created by `Object.create(null)`) is returned.

> Will that return value be a reference to the exact same `down` the
> callbacks are accessing?

Yes.

> I thought local variables could only be accessed by inner functions?

A variable is a pairing of an identifier (ie. the name of the variable) and a value.

Scope is the region of code over which an identifier (in this case "`down`") has a specific meaning.

The scope of an identifier is determined by the way in which the variable is declared (`const`/`let`/`var`/implicit in non-strict mode). Variable `down` is declared using `let`; its scope is therefore the nearest containing block, which is the function `trackKeys`.

Functions declared inside `trackKeys` will close over `down` via the built-in closure-forming mechanism of JavaScript, and will therefore share the meaning of the identifier "down".

Note: if inner functions or blocks *also* declare their own variable named `"down"` these inner variables will either result in an error (`var` in a non-function block in strict mode, duplicate declaration), do nothing (`var` in non-strict mode in a non-function block), or shadow (hide from view) the outer variable (`let`/`const`).

Returning `down` does not change the scope of the identifier `down`. Trying to refer to "down" outside `trackKeys` will continue to error or return undefined depending on whether you are in strict mode. Returning the value of `down` does, however, make this value available outside `trackKeys`.

Comment: Not exactly - all variables in JS are passed by value, it's just that the value happens to be a reference to an object; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: Correct.........